# Error message when creating a shared folder

Tags: samba, shared-folders

I log in as administrator, but I get this message when I try to create a shared folder:

```
'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error Permission denied

You do not have permission to create a usershare. Ask your administrator to grant you permissions to create a share.
```

How do I give myself full permissions?